# Agg Function Display Ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using the `sum` aggregate function as part of my col def. This changes the `headerName` of the column to `sum(gold)`, is there a way of changing this displayed text to something else or not having any text at all so it just shows the column name e.g. just displays "**gold**".

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `suppressAggFuncInHeader` on your grid to `true`.

[suppressAggFuncInHeader](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grid-properties/#reference-rowPivoting):

> When true, column headers won't include the aggFunc, e.g. 'sum(Bank Balance)' will just be 'Bank Balance'.

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/CmeDnRwBBiH3LjBg).